# What is a “color image” filter generally used for?

Tags: filters, color-filters

I purchased a **Kenko Color Filter** by mistake.

[image]

I am not sure what it is used for and what kind of results it produces.

I’ve used filters with two colors before and they have a gradient between them but here it’s just two colors with a neat separation between them.

I was not able to find information online about them.

Comment: Can you create a gradient effect using a wider aperture and focusing in the distance, to blur the actual view of the filter?

Answer (score 2):

My answer will be a bit of speculation. This filter (purple/yellow) is used for landscape photos to add more intense blue (purple) in the sky and more yellow/warm in the ground. Here is one extreme example just to show the effect:
[image]
Left is original, right is image with filters.

Answer (score 1):

It's just a "special effect" filter to tint your images half purple and half yellow... pretty much useless IMO.

Comment: Haha ok. Wondering if someone had an example of a result obtained using it that would be inspiring but maybe not 

Comment: I guess it should also give you half purple half yellow bokeh balls.